# Off-topic question closings with no reason given

Tags: discussion

In the last few weeks I have seen several questions appear in the close review queue that say "Should this question be closed as: off-topic?". However, when I click on the Close button, the dialog panel that pops-up doesn't have off-topic nor any of the off-topic sub-reasons checked. Further, if I look at the question on the page where it is posted, it does not have any prior close vote counts on it.

I don't understand how such items get into the close review queue nor what I'm expected to do with them. Any explanation or advice?

Answer (score 4):

Users with less than 3k rep can only flag to close a question. When they do so, it goes to the review queue for review by users who have the privilege of voting to close. Because they were sent to the queue via flags, they do not have an accompanying close vote.

Review and vote on them as you would any other question in the review queue. In addition, these users get their flag marked "helpful" if it gets a single additional close vote and "unhelpful" only if all the reviewers mark it "Leave open". So if you really think that the question was flagged incorrectly, mark it "Leave open" and perhaps explain why you are voting as such in the comments. Hopefully, the flagger will see it and learn from it or at least, the other reviewers will see it and take your comments into consideration when casting their vote.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and advice. Is there anything in the moderator's tools that would lest me see the flag?

Comment: @m_go What you're seeing is pretty much all there is to the flag... they simply flagged to close it. Only moderators are shown who flagged it. IIRC, all closure flags are now routed through the review system. Certain other types of flags, such as "Low quality" or "Not an answer" or comment flags might be shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged). There might also be a lag involved... i.e., users are shown the flag only if a moderator hasn't gotten to it within X minutes or so. You might have also seen a yellow indicator sometimes. "Other" flags are never shown to users.